# How do I resolve this error in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, path, driver

```
Code:


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,BiffException{


     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\wer\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            WebDriver driver;

                 driver =new InternetExplorerDriver();

                       File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\wer\\Desktop\\Demo\\sai.xls");





           Workbook wbk;

           wbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(f1);

           Sheet sheet = wbk.getSheet(0);
           String username;

           username = sheet.getCell(0, 0).getContents();





Error:
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\wer\Desktop\Demo\sai.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:213)
       at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
       at test.main(test.java:98)
```

I have placed the file in the path specified, but I am still getting this error.

When I give find absolute file path, the file path that I get is:

> C:\Users\wer\Desktop\Demo\sai.xls

Comment: And you're certain that the file `C:\Users\wer\Desktop\Demo\sai.xls` exists? As it does not seems to exists :-). It does not seems to have anything to do with Selenium so far.

Comment: Definitely nothing to do with Selenium. The only Selenium-related code is the `new InternetExplorerDriver()` and that instance is not even used.

Comment: It's not related to Selenium. It's related to the way you handling the file.

Comment: ok the problem is not with selenium, fine.

Comment: how to resolve this error, I am sure that the file is placed in the mentioned path.

Comment: @dee Double check the extension and everything in the path. One way to do this, open up a command prompt, and go to the file in windows explorer. Drag the file into your command prompt, this will show you the full path and file name you should be using. The file not being found means you have something wrong there, or maybe your running this remotely and the machine it's running on doesn't have the file.